# How to perform search operation on static pages of cakephp

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, static, controller

I am using cakephp 2.0 for a site, in this i have pages controller containing all the static pages like about-us, company, services,... I wanted to use search plugin for user to search through the view content. But i was not able to find any plugin that could help me target **static pages** for searching. Can anyone help me get an idea for implementing search functionality on static pages.

Thankyou

Comment: are the contents of those static pages in your database? as they should be for such a search? or in the files?

Comment: Hey mark, thanks for the response, the static pages are just basic .ctp files, which might be updated occasionally, these are not associated with database. I wanted to avoid using database as i believe they are going to be few in number and also to improve performance a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to search static pages as they are just files on disk.

You have three options

- Build a model to hold the data somewhat like a CMS so you can use
  mysql search.
- google search for sites
- the more hacky approach of
  reading the contents of all the pages and using preg_match() or
  similar on the contents to find matches.

The first option is probably the best depending on your use case. The second option is the easiest if its public facing content. The third option is a horrible idea

Comment: Thank you for quick response, I was not sure whether in the site the pages will grow more or be few; so i was just was looking for a "content search" solution for just static pages within Cakephp where i would avoid using any database tables. From your suggestion i am considering to go for first choice if in future there will be lot of content pages getting added, else i would use google search.